# What is the difference between $b and $$b?

Tags: php

I have doubt regrading '$' usage in PHP.
In php is their any difference between between `$b` and `$$b`?
What will be the output then for `$b` and `$$b`?

Comment: Read here http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: `user3085676` asks , `user3085576` answers O.o

Comment: user3085676 vs user3085676

Comment: This is a fairly valid question, but had you typed it in to Google, you would have gotten your answer without going through the hassle of being massively downvoted on SO :|

Comment: First i am sorry that i answered my own question.Because i got an answer from  google itself. As i wanted to share what i got, i answered and shared with people.

People come here to get a complex solution explained in a simple way.Google has everything in it i agree.. If all looks in google then why we would use stackoverflow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only difference between $message and $$b is that, $b is a normal variable and $$bis variable to variable. The difference in functioning is shown below:

When declaring a variable in PHP the variable gets declared like this

```
$b//which is simply a variable
```

To store the data to assign the value to it we write like

```
$b= “ride”; //assigned the string to the variable

echo $b; // it will print the value
```

Whereas if you want to display the variable to variable then you use

```
$var="Hello";

$b="var";

echo $b; //print var

echo $$b; //print Hello.
```

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

A normal variable is set with a statement such as:

```
$a = 'hello';
```

A variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a variable. In the above example, `hello`, can be used as the name of a variable by using two dollar signs. i.e.

```
$$a = 'world';
```

At this point two variables have been defined and stored in the PHP symbol tree: `$a` with contents *"hello"* and `$hello` with contents *"world"*.